# Edit existing Profile Properties in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, ssp

I have to edit Company Name profile property in SSP. It is not allowing me edit or delete property. I need to change length value from 250 to 50. How can I do that? Can we set through code?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to Sharepoint database, you can definitely do it directly there (which I do not recommend unless you're completely sure what you are doing).

Comment: In which database table I can do that? Please let me know.

Comment: I think it should be in table Lists in Content database. As I remember it contains something like 'fields' column, but I don't remember how data is represented there.

Comment: If you access any of the SharePoint databases in another way than via the object model, you will lose MS support for you entire farm.

Comment: Not to mention that an update can mess up your changes, or your change can mess up the update.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can't delete the property, you should be able to hide it and create another one with the same display name.

Comment: There is no global hide option, but there are settings for if/how it displays on the profile/edit details pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this property is mapped to an Active Directory property. If it is then go to AD manager and change the propertie's properties there :)